# Vector addition operation

Tags: c++, linux, vector, g++

I am trying to add two Vectors below is the code snippet :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        unsigned int i = 0;
        vector <float> v1;
        vector <float> v2;
        vector <float> v3;



        cout << "Filling the Numbers\n";
        for (i=5;i < 125 ; i = i + 5) {
            v1.push_back(i/10);
            v2.push_back(i/100);
        }

        cout << "Adding the numbers\n";
        for (i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
                v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
        }

        cout << "Printing the numbers\n";
                for (i = 0; i < v3.size() ; i++) {
                        cout << v3[i];
                }


        return 0;
}
```

The program is crashing at Line 18. It seems to me I need to do operator overloading for + operation. Please help.

Comment: Where is line 18? What do you mean by "crash"? Does it compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform a pairwise binary operation between the elements of two containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541276/how-do-i-perform-a-pairwise-binary-operation-between-the-elements-of-two-contain)

Comment: @underscore_d: This question has been asked in '10...

Comment: @Pixelchemist I'm not aware that it matters when a thread was posted, if it might be relevant to/better than the current one. Other users are free to ignore the duplicate flag, but it at least gets a link to a potentially useful resource into this one. That said, now that I look at it, I'm not 100% certain that was the thread I was really thinking of... but oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line doesn't work, because there's no `v3[i]` allocated:

```
v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
```

You have two choices, either use 'push_back'

```
v3.push_back( v1[i] + v2[i] );
```

Or resize the array to the given size before hand:

```
v3.resize( v1.size() );
```

If you push_back, it will be nice to preallocate the space anyway:

```
v3.reserve( v1.size() );
```

And finally, you can try to read up on [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) instead, as those operations are already built into it!

**Edit:** and yes, as Johannes noted, you have a problem with floating point division :>

Answer (score 11):

To avoid the obvious pitfalls you encountered, you can do this as an alternative:

```
#include <algorithm> // for transform
#include <functional> // for plus

std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), std::back_inserter(v3), std::plus<float>());
```

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Comment: Nice, much cleaner than double for loop iteration I was using. Any idea if this way is actually faster?

Comment: @saccharine: It should be as fast as the best loop you can write. All of the work in `std::transform` happens by the magic of templates, so it gets heavily optimized and inlined, and should produce exactly the same object code as a naïve loop.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to do a floating point division

```
v1.push_back(i/10.0f);
v2.push_back(i/100.0f);
```

Then you need to have space for `i` variables on `v3` or use `push_back`

```
v3.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);
```

Comment: +1: for noting the other problem that everyone else (including myself) seemed to overlook :D

Answer (score 1):

> `v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];`

You are assigning to elements that do not exist. Try `v3.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);` instead.

Also, you probably want `i/10.0` instead of `i/10`, otherwise your results are rounded.

Answer (score 1):

You write into the v3 vector, but you haven't allocated any space for it.

Try to add:

```
 v3.reserve (v1.size());
```

between your first and second loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is v3[i] doesn't work as the vector starts off having zero elements. What you want to do is either:

```
v3.push_back( v1[i] + v2[i] );
```

or preallocate the vector

```
v3.resize( v1.size() );
```

OR the final solution, which I would do is

```
v3.reserve( v1.size() );

for (i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
    v3.push_back( v1[i] + v2[i] );
}
```

as this avoid resizing the vector again and again.